# Not sure how to resolve null aware before operator

Tags: dart

I'm getting a warning

```
The left operand uses '?.', so its value can be null
```

from this line of code

```
code = username?.hashCode % 7 ?? 0 % 7;
```

Not sure what the best practise is and why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use the `% 7` operator before you do your null check. You might be calling `null % 7`, which definitely won't work. Move that outside of your null check.

```dart
code = (username?.hashCode ?? 0) % 7;
```